# my bash PS1 cannot get git branch

Tags: bash

I configure bash PS1 from https://bashrcgenerator.com/

and its PS1 to get git branch is:

```
export PS1="\$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/')\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

but it cannot get git branch and display only `()`

```bash
()git branch 2>/dev/null
master
()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are under a git repository? Your `PS1` actually shows`(master)` if my current working directory is a git repo, if it is not, then shows me absolutely nothing.

Comment: Btw, you can use `git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null` to get the current branch name.

Comment: Also, there is absolutely no need to _export_ the variable.

Comment: I added a picture. I can use `git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null` to get the current branch name. but PS1 cannot display.

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu what operating system are you using? Maybe it's different how `PS1` behaves

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883416/adding-git-branch-on-the-bash-command-prompt). And about using `git branch 2> /dev/null` there's not need to use `| sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'`.

Comment: And when you want to respond in comments if there are two or more users in comments section you should use `@` followed by its name like this: `@Firestar-Reimu`. Otherwise they will not get any notification about your comment.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I use ArchLinux and it is the current version. [git-prompt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) does the work

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu not sure why your setting is not working. But glad about `git-prompt` worked for you :).